# Furigana in Swing (Or GUI Alternatives ...)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ruby-characters

Put simple, I cannot find a way to easily display furigana in a JLabel.

For the record:

> Furigana (振り仮名?) is a Japanese reading
>   aid, consisting of smaller kana, or
>   syllabic characters, printed next to a
>   kanji (ideographic character) or other
>   character to indicate its
>   pronunciation. In horizontal text,
>   yokogaki, they are placed above the
>   line of text, while in vertical text,
>   tategaki, they are placed to the right
>   of the line of text, as illustrated
>   below. It is one type of ruby text.
>   Furigana are also known as yomigana
>   (読み仮名?) or rubi (ルビ?) in Japanese.

In XHTML this is supported with the [Ruby Annotation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-ruby-20010531/) element, which is - in turn - not supported by Swing's limited HTML rendering capabilities.

I've recently tried to create a `JRubyLabel` class, capable of handeling Ruby Annotation elements, by stacking multiple `JLabel` elements in a `JPanel` - however, I am not so very familiar with Swing, so in a sense I feel like I'm over-complicating things.

My questions thus are, in order of preference:

- Does Swing support the displaying of ruby text?
- Can you see a simpler, or better way of implementing ruby text in Swing?
- Lastly, is there any other GUI program - preferably for Java - that *does* support ruby text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Itadaki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itadaki/) Source Forge project supports Furigana in Java Swing.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the link here is totally busted.

Comment: @Makoto: Updated broken link.